# Writing content to file in Hadoop HDFS using C#.NET

Tags: c#, json, .net, hadoop

I have a requirement to write data to file in `Hadoop`. I could read the `.json` content from `Hadoop` by referring this site https://kontext.tech/column/visual_csharp/252/invoke-hadoop-webhdfs-apis-in-net-core, but since I'm new with this technology, I have no idea how to write content using `C# .Net`. How could I do it?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think any programming language can work with [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html). (Cause it's just REST calls.)

Here's an example of how to work with it.:

> Create and Write to a File Step 1: Submit a HTTP PUT request without
> automatically following redirects and without sending the file data.
>
> ```
> curl -i -X PUT "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE
>                     [&overwrite=<true|false>][&blocksize=<LONG>][&replication=<SHORT>]
>                     [&permission=<OCTAL>][&buffersize=<INT>]"
> ```
>
> The request is redirected to a datanode where the file data is to be written:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
> Location: http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE...
> Content-Length: 0
> ```
>
> Step 2: Submit another HTTP PUT request using the URL in the Location header with the file data to be written. `curl -i -X PUT -T <LOCAL_FILE> "http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE...`"
>
> The client receives a 201 Created response with zero content length and the WebHDFS URI of the file in the Location header:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
> Location: webhdfs://<HOST>:<PORT>/<PATH>
> Content-Length: 0
> ```